# How to know a number reach limit integer

Tags: javascript, numbers, int

> Assume we are dealing with an environment which could only store integers within the 32-bit signed integer range: [−2<sup>31</sup>,  2<sup>31</sup> − 1]. For the purpose of this problem, assume that your function returns 0 when the reversed integer overflows.

The problem I have is how to know that a number is greater than integer range. *(Sorry for my English)*

Comment: You can check this.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger

Answer (score 1):

You could get the values from [Signed 32-bit integers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Signed_32-bit_integers) and check the range.

```js
function getValue(v) {
    return v < -2147483648 || v > 2147483647
        ? 0
        : v;
}

console.log(getValue(1));
console.log(getValue(1e20));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since JavaScript's numbers are not ints (and have a **much** broader range), you can just compare your result with the required range:

```
if (result < -(2**31) || result > (2**31) - 1) {
    // Out of range
}
```

(`**` is the newish exponentiation operator. For older JavaScript engines, you'd use `-Math.pow(2, 31)` and `Math.pow(2, 31) - 1` instead. Or of course, just calculate it in advance: -2147483648 and 2147483647.)

Or, assuming your result is not fractional (it's a whole number), you can make JavaScript convert it to a 32-bit signed int using a bitwise operator, and see if you still have the same number:

```
if (result !== result|0) {
    // Out of range
}
```

That works because the bitwise `|` operator converts both of its operands to 32-bit signed ints, does the bitwise OR operation, and then converts the result back to a number. So if it were out of range, you wouldn't get back the same number.